# Sort objects inside array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I have an array of object and want to reorder objects inside array Is there any way to do that?

```
var obj = [ {start: 12, end: 14}, {start: 2, end:8}]
```

I should check if start date of first object is greater than second object's start date and change objects order, The result in this case should be =>

```
var obj = [ {start: 2, end:8}, {start: 12, end: 14}]
```

I know about sorting inside object but cant find way to reorder the whole object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting an array of objects by property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-property-values)

Comment: Take a look at `Array.prototype.sort` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: That solved my problem thanks

Comment: Please don't remove the before and after code samples; these are required to get good answers and to identify good duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use your expeceted property to conduct compared function

```js
var obj = [
  { start: 12, end: 14 },
  { start: 2, end: 8 },
]

const res = obj.sort((a, b) => a.start - b.start)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Always good to have a warning that `Array.prototype.sort` is *in place* and does modify the array that is being sorted (and not just the returned array).